# space leak in simple string generation. why?

Tags: haskell

```
-- generates names in the following order
-- a, b, c ... z, aa, ba, ca, ... za, ab, bb, cb ...
nextName :: String -> String
nextName [] = "a"
nextName (x:xs) = if x == 'z' then 'a' : nextName xs else succ x : xs

-- verify if the number of names generated is as expected.
countNames :: String -> String -> Int
countNames start end = loop 1 start
    where
        loop acc next =
            if next == end then
                acc
            else
                loop (acc + 1) (nextName next)
```

run `countNames "a" "zzzzzz"` in ghci

running it on my com takes up the whole of the memory and takes a hell of lot of time to complete.

appreciate it if anyone indicate where and why space leak is happening?

Comment: Make `loop` strict on its arguments.

Comment: how are you compiling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is a large counter thunk because loop is not strict on the counter `acc`. The usual solution is to use `seq` or `BangPatterns` to make it strict. Here is the solution using `BangPatterns`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
-- generates names in the following order
-- a, b, c ... z, aa, ba, ca, ... za, ab, bb, cb ...
nextName :: String -> String
nextName [] = "a"
nextName (x:xs) = if x == 'z' then 'a' : nextName xs else succ x : xs

-- verify if the number of names generated is as expected.

countNames :: String -> String -> Int
countNames start end = loop 1 start
    where
        loop !acc next =
            if next == end then
                acc
            else
                loop (acc + 1) (nextName next)
```

Comment: Why is it that that GHC strictness analyzer doesn't (can't?) catch this sort of simple accumulator? This sort of thing catches nearly every beginning Haskeller and for good reason. When I was starting out and heard about the strictness analyzer, I assumed that at very least it would strictly evaluate a simple integer sum. It wasn't until I spent an afternoon chasing down a stack overflow that I realized how wrong I was.

Comment: You may have a look at this page: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Strictness#Strictness_analysis tl;dr: Strictness analysis is not performed by default, you should use "-O" flag.

Answer (score 5):

While using strict evaluation fix your issue, I would recommend you to reuse standard function to compute the interval length:

```
countNames :: String -> String -> Int
countNames start end = (+) 1 . length . takeWhile (/= end) $ iterate nextName start
```

Explanation:

- `iterate` generate an infinite list of `nextName`: `[start, nextname start, nextname (nextName start), ...]`;
- `takeWhile (/= end)` keep the list elements until you reach the expected value (excluding the upper bound);
- then you take the `length` and add 1.

Comment: didn't know about iterate. thats really useful. learned something. thanks.